# How to check if key in Interface is a class that extends a specific Parent class?

Tags: class, typescript, prototype

In typescript, for an interface, is there a way to enforce the type of a property to be the "child subclass C, that extends class P"?

example.ts

```
import { P } from '/path/to/types'
class C extends P {
   ...
}
```

types.ts

```
// `C` is not accessible here
class P {
   ...
}


interface {
    myProp: ???? <-- how to enforce `myProp` is a subclass of P (class, not instance)?
}
```

Alternatively, I can check `Object.getPrototypeOf(myProp.prototype) === P.prototype`, but that is at runtime.  Is there a way to enforce this condition via types during compile/checker time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to get the type:

```
class P { ... }
interface Foo {
    myProp: typeof P
}
//Usage
class C extends P { ... }
class D { ... }
//Ok
var f: Foo = {
    myProp: C
}
// Error
var f2: Foo = {
    myProp: D
}
```

This will ensure that the class specified as the property will be compatible with `P`.

**Edit**

Since Typescript uses structural compatibility, any class that has the same structure as `P` will be compatible with `typeof P`. If `P`  has only public members and a small number of members, there may be a risk that another class may unwittingly have the same structure. To ensure that only classes directly inheriting `P` are compatible, you can add a private member to `P` that makes `P` incompatible with other classes (even ones with the same structure, different declarations of private fields are not compatible with each other)

```
class P { private nonStructural:true }
interface Foo {
    myProp: typeof P
}
//Usage
class C extends P { }
class D { private nonStructural:true }
//Ok
var f: Foo = {
    myProp: C
}
// Error
var f2: Foo = {
    myProp: D
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I noticed that D will still pass the check if it has the same methods as P, but I guess internally it's just checking if the prototypes have the same keys.

Comment: @EricRen edited the answer to add a workaround for structural compatibility.